# Practical Opamp Buffer Output Offset and Clipping Behavior

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer

I'm designing a full-wave precision rectifier using OP07 in LTSpice. The first stage of the circuit (shown below) buffers the AC input using an OP07.

[image: Schematic]

But the buffer output is clipped with a significant DC offset at 10 V input when the peak of the non-inverting terminal input is approximately 1.6 V:
[image: Buffer output for 10 V input]

The buffer output is also clipped at 2 V input when the peak of the non-inverting terminal input is approximately 0.5 V, with the output waveform distorted:
[image: Buffer output for 2 V input]

Both these non-inverting terminal voltages are below ±VDD. I observed a similar behavior on replacing the OP07 with the MAX4352.

Of course, the circuit with the OP07 replaced by a universal opamp - a single-pole opamp with no limits on output voltage swing - exactly buffers the input as expected, without any offset or clipping for both 10 V and 2 V inputs.
[image: Universal opamp buffer output for 10 V input]

Why are MAX4352 and OP07 buffer outputs clipped and offset even though the non-inverting terminal voltage does not exceed ±VDD?

**EDIT**: As [periblepsis](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/330261/periblepsis) and [Andy aka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/20218/andy-aka) pointed out, I messed up with the supply connections. The circuit now works as expected:
[image]

Comment: Isn't your +Vdd just 0 V?

Comment: Ahh, indeed it is, I missed it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set-up your op-amp power supplies incorrectly. V2 positive is tied to ground and, of course V2 negative is at -12 volts but then, for V1, you have its negative terminal connected to -VDD when it should connect to ground: -

[image]

Alternatively leave as is but change V1's voltage to be 24 volts.

Comment: Oh no, I missed checking the supply somehow. Thank you for pointing this out!